# PHP get JSON object value from Input array (array-like name)

Tags: php, arrays, json, string

I have 3 inputs like this:

```
<input type="text" name="product[1][name]" >
<input type="text" name="product[1][cost]" >
<input type="text" name="product[1][qty]"  >
```

... which goes until n products

```
<input type="text" name="product[n][name]" >
<input type="text" name="product[n][cost]" >
<input type="text" name="product[n][qty]"  >
```

and based on the input value a JSON string like this:

```
{"product[1][name]": "Prod1", "product[1][cost]": "100$", "product[1][qty]": "3", "product[2][name]": "Prod2", ... }
```

how can I retrieve their name and value because neither `json_decode` function can take their values because of the **array-like name**

```
$decodedObject=json_decode($array['data']); // this data contains the json string
echo $decodedObject->product; // does not work
echo $decodedObject->product[1][qty]; // does not work
```

is there any simple way?
Or the only way is to cut the name like `product[`, take the inside elements , and the value after the `:` and so on?

But how can I even take the object from it without letting PHP know that's not an array ?

Comment: How are you creating that JSON?

Comment: @El_Vanja that JSON is created from a form, every form input is taken and translated into a JSON string, then uploaded in a database. 
I want to retrieve the "product[x][name]" from that JSON string which I will take from database.

Comment: Which REQUEST parameter are you using to fetch the form values? I think you'd be better off processing that array into a proper JSON object and storing that in the DB for later retreival.

Comment: @Alex.Barylski I send the form data to an AJAX script that inserts it into the database as a VARCHAR datatype, if that was the question :)

Comment: There are ways but the way the Json is created is making things complicated.

Comment: @nice_dev you are right, is any way to transform it into a simple string and then simplify it further? If not I think the best solution is to redo the JSON completely...

Comment: @Lepy Why do you want to make it a JSON and then send to server? Why not just do a HTML form post?

Comment: @nice_dev because it does a form post simultaneous, while showing another page with the form inputs it also sends it to ajax. ( the next page after form is a printing page )

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I found an alternative. The problem is that this:

```
$decodedObject=json_decode($array['data']); // will create an object
```

will not transform it in an array, instead I have used this:

```
$decodedObject=json_decode($array['data'], true); // will create an array
```

after that I had checked how many objects exist, and then just add them to another array:

```
$i=1;
while(isset($decodedObject["product[$i][qty]"])) // while any element exists
{
    $newProducs= array();
    $newProducs['name'] = $decodedObject["product[$i][name]"];
    $newProducs['cost'] = $decodedObject["product[$i][cost]"];
    $newProducs['qty'] = $decodedObject["product[$i][qty]"];
    array_push($products, $newProducs); // optional: add to the main array (products) the new-created array (newProducs)
    $i++; //increment to search another product
}
```

The problem was that I was not fully creating an array -_-

**While this is not the full answer I still hope somebody will find a better solution and not a change.**